# How to delete outside of a clipping mask, containing the layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, crop, clipping-mask

For a landscape architecture project, I have made a very big scaled masterplan. For the next fase, I want to make a detailed zoom in of a specific part of the site.

For this, I have to enlarge the image 3x, making it excessively big. I managed to make a clipping mask, containing the different layers, but the information of the rest of the drawing (which I don't need anymore) is still present (outside of the clipping mask), I can't even save my file.

Is there a way to crop a drawing, containing the layers? I tried doing it through expanding and cropping (pathfinder) but it just merged all my layers together again.

Answer (score 1):

Make a second Illustrator file, then place the first file into it twice. Leave one of the placed Illustrator files as 100% size, and adjust the placement to match the artboard.

Take the second placed file and scale it to 300%, then create a clipping mask over the proper are you want to highlight. Next, move the clipped version around on the document to wherever you would like it to be.

This way, if you need to make changes to the base architecture project, you can do so in the original file. Then open your second file, let the placed images update, and resave.